# iOS8 Autolayout Rotation with iPad does not seem to correctly re-size collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, rotation, autolayout

I have a collection view added as a subview to `self.view` and autolayout constraints are just stretch to edges.

I'm trying to achieve a solution where the rotation properly re-sizes the contents of the collection view.

Landscape

[image: Screenshot 2015-08-08 21.25.01.png]

And then if you rotate to portrait

[image: Screenshot 2015-08-08 21.25.13.png]

How can I achieve this?

The strange thing is if I present a `viewcontroller` modally and dismiss it, the underlying `collectionView` will get resized on dismissal.

Comment: Hey, collection view have normal resize, may be problem with collection view cell resize?

Comment: i think after rotation need to reloadData so the sizeForItem is called again, and it re-lays out. but its so ugly :(

Comment: can give me some code? i can help....

Comment: you can put part of your project in dropbox, and give me link

Comment: cool, in what there was a problem? in cells size?

Answer (score 1):

This will help to resize the contents on rotation
`
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator {

```
[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
} completion:nil];
```

}`